# Invalid message property name: Content-Length

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I'm trying to push a message to Websphere queue. I use a HTTP client and it sends a message to that queue via JMS. I got this error `Invalid message property name: Content-Length`. I think issue would be some conversion problem to HTTP to JMS. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`-` is invalid for a JMS header.

How are you mapping your HTTP request to a JMS message?

The mapping needs to exclude headers like this.